# How to check and create dynamic email aliases with flurdy and php?

Tags: php, email, alias, postfix-mta

I am having a SNS which allows public users to register and create their own profiles. I want to create an email alias when a new user registers.

For example when "Joe" registers, I want to offer him an email address like "joe@mydomain.com".

I have setup a mail server using the instructions given at http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/#install

I have gone through the flurdy documentation and done a lot of research to create an email alias via php. Couldn't find any useful one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the offers above the text box, then place it in `<div>` just above the text box for email or right side of the text box.

if you want to input the offer right inside the text box, try `value="<?php echo $email" ?>` set `$email` variable as

`$email = $_POST['first_name']."_".$_POST['last_name']."@yourdomain.com";`

add event with jquery `onKeyup=` event to `last_name` text box.

Comment: I Know how to echo that things. This is not what I am looking for. I need help in creating a php script which can connect with mail server and generate email aliases dynamically.

Comment: post your `php` what you have coded right now. We might help once we get the blue print to enhance it.